# Yii2 Kartik fileinput Issue

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I have create a file input field in yii2 using kartik fileinput widget.Just see the code below

```
<?=FileInput::widget([
    'name' => 'pictures[]',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'showPreview' => false,
        'showCaption' => false,
        'showRemove' => false,
        'showUpload' => false,
        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-block',
        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
        'browseLabel' =>  'Select Photo'
    ],
    'options' => [
      'accept' => 'image/*',
      'multiple' => true],
]);
```

And here is my output[image]

How to hide the highlighted button.I mean cancel button

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the cancel button with the `showCancel`, as you do with the other properties:

```
'pluginOptions' => [
        'showPreview' => false,
        'showCaption' => false,
        'showRemove' => false,
        'showCancel' => false, // <--- HERE
        'showUpload' => false,
        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-block',
        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
        'browseLabel' =>  'Select Photo'
],
```

You can check all the props and options in the javascript documentation (It is more complete than the Yii2 one).

[Kartik Boostrap FileInput options](https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-options)